# How to set state of a component when a global variable changes?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

My app component has 2 child components, of one which has an onClick which passes props to another function, where a global variable is changed. I need the other child component to setState to the value of this variable whenever it gets changed.

```
function ChordButton(props) {
    return(
        <p onClick={() => {createChordInversion(props.intervals, selectedInversion)}>
         {props.chordName}</p>
    )
}

function createChordInversion(intervals, a){
    newArr = [...intervals]
    for(var i = 0; i < a; i++){
        newArr[i]= newArr[i] + 12;
    }
    newArr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    // need newArr to be observed by Keys at this point
    var chordInversion = newArr.map(x => x - (newArr[0] - 1))
    playChord(chordInversion);
}


function Keys(){
    const [intervalArray, setIntervalArray] = useState([0])
    // setIntervalArray(newArr) this causes infinite renders
    return(...
```

Is this possible with useState or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible with `useState` if you pass the setter e.g `setIntervalArray` as a prop that you use in the child component to change the state.

When there are multiple children (and levels of nesting), consider using [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)